# Vectorized calculation of grouped metrics in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Using Tensorflow, I need to calculate multiple grouped metrics (e.g. mean) from a tensor, based on groups that are given by a second tensor.

A a toy example, let's say I got:  
`values = tf.constant([[1], [1.5], [2], [2.5], [3], [3.5]])`
`groupings = tf.constant([1,3,2,1,2,3])`

And want to calculate:
`group_means = [1.75,2.5,2.5])`

I know how to calculate the mean for one group, e.g.:
`group = tf.boolean_mask(values, tf.equal(groupings, i))` 
`mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(group,axis=0)`
and could do that for every group in a for-loop.

What I can't figure out is how to do that in a vectorized manner without looping through each group. Maybe it is a very easy question with an obvious solution, but I appreaciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`tf.math.unsorted_segment_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/unsorted_segment_mean):

```
import tensorflow as tf

values = tf.constant([[1], [1.5], [2], [2.5], [3], [3.5]])
groupings = tf.constant([1,3,2,1,2,3]) - 1
tf.math.unsorted_segment_mean(values, groupings, tf.shape(tf.unique_with_counts(groupings)[-1])[-1])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1.75],
       [2.5 ],
       [2.5 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Note that I subtract 1 from `groupings`, since it is easier when `segment_ids` start from 0.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware, that there exist an implementation of a grouped mean. Thank you. 
But I see correctly, that there's not general 'groupby'/segmentation functionality, that could be used for more complex metrics (e.g. other moments)?

Comment: Not directly..but surely possible.